# Writing a function with structures and array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

The assignment was the following, you have been asked to write a program that will sort information on when the TAs for COP 3223 are available. Your program will read in data on all TA office hour shifts, sort the data, then print out the information in a pre-specified format. You may assume that the maximum number of shifts is 100.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Shift
{
char name[100];
char day_of_week[100];
int start_hour;
int end_hour;
};

struct Shift shift_data[100];
struct Shift temp;

int read_data(struct Shift shift_data[], int *num_shifts);
void sort_data(struct Shift shift_data[], int *num_shifts);
void print_data(struct Shift shift[], int num_shifts);

int main(void)
{
int num_shifts;

read_data(shift_data, &num_shifts);

sort_data(shift_data, &num_shifts);

print_data(shift_data, num_shifts);

return 0;
}

   /*** Preconditions: array of structure "Shift" to store data
 Postconditions: number of shifts read in from data file
 Actions: Ask user for name of input file. Read the number of shifts, then read in the data for all
      of the shifts. Return the number of shifts. ***/
int read_data(struct Shift shift_data[], int *num_shifts)
{
char input_schedule[100];
int i;
char shift_name[100], shift_day[100];

printf("Enter the name of the input file.\n");
scanf("%s", &input_schedule[100]);

FILE *ifp;
ifp = fopen("input_schedule.txt", "r");
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &num_shifts);

for(i=0; i<(*num_shifts); i++)
{
 fscanf(ifp, "%s %s %d %d\n", &shift_data[i].name, &shift_data[i].day_of_week, &shift_data[i].start_hour, &shift_data[i].end_hour);
}
fclose(ifp);
return num_shifts;
}
/*** Preconditions: array of structure "Shift" integer value indicating number of shifts
 Postconditions: none - this function does not return anything.
 Actions: Sort the shifts by the TA's first name. ***/
void sort_data(struct Shift shift_data[], int *num_shifts)
{
int i,j;

for(i=0; i<(*num_shifts); i++)
{
for(j=i+1; j<(*num_shifts); j++)
{
    if(strcmp(shift_data[i].name,shift_data[i].name) < 0)
    {
        temp.name = shift_data[i].name;
        shift_data[i].name = shift_data[j].name;
        shift_data[j].name = temp.name;
    }
    if(strcmp(shift_data[i].day_of_week,shift_data[i].day_of_week) < 0)
    {
        temp.day_of_week = shift_data[i].day_of_week;
        shift_data[i].day_of_week = shift_data[j].day_of_week;
        shift_data[j].day_of_week = temp.day_of_week;
    }
    if(strcmp(shift_data[i].start_hour,shift_data[i].start_hour) < 0)
    {
        temp.start_hour = shift_data[i].start_hour;
        shift_data[i].start_hour = shift_data[j].start_hour;
        shift_data[j].start_hour = temp.start_hour;
    }
    if(strcmp(shift_data[i].end_hour,shift_data[i].end_hour) < 0)
    {
        temp.end_hour = shift_data[i].end_hour;
        shift_data[i].end_hour = shift_data[j].end_hour;
        shift_data[j].end_hour = temp.end_hour;
    }
}

}
}

 /*** Preconditions: array of structure "Shift" integer value indicating number of shifts
 Postconditions: none - this function does not return anything.
 Actions: Print the sorted data in the format described below. **/
void print_data(struct Shift shift[], int num_shifts)
{
int i;

printf("\n\n\n");

for(i=0; i<num_shifts; i++)
{
printf("%s\t\t", shift_data[i].name);
printf("%s\t", shift_data[i].day_of_week);
printf("%d to ", shift_data[i].start_hour);
printf("%d\n", shift_data[i].end_hour);

if(shift_data[i].start_hour > 12)
{
    shift_data[i].start_hour = shift_data[i].start_hour - 12;
    printf("%2d:00 pm to  ", shift_data[i].start_hour);
}
else if(shift_data[i].start_hour < 12)
{
    printf("%2d:00 am to  ", shift_data[i].start_hour);
}
else if(shift_data[i].start_hour == 12)
{
    printf("%2d:00 pm to  ", shift_data[i].start_hour);
}

if(shift_data[i].end_hour > 12)
{
    shift_data[i].end_hour = shift_data[i].end_hour - 12;
    printf("%2d:00 pm\n", shift_data[i].end_hour);
}
else if(shift_data[i].end_hour < 12)
{
    printf("%2d:00 am\n", shift_data[i].end_hour);
}
else if(shift_data[i].end_hour == 12)
{
    printf("%2d:00 pm\n", shift_data[i].end_hour);
}
}
}
```

However I am having a problem in the sort_data function with my temporary variable. I keep getting the error message, error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[100]' from type 'char *'

Comment: in the read_data aren't you supposed to recieve a structure array? you're receiving a integer

Answer (score 1):

After you've got the number of shifts, it's really simple afterwards. You can just loop `num_shifts` times and scan the corresponding values.
Something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < num_shifts; i++)
{
    int ret = fscanf(ifp, "%99s %99s %d %d\n",
                    shift_data[i].name, 
                    shift_data[i].day_of_week,
                    &shift_data[i].start_hour,
                    &shift_data[i].end_hour);
}
```

Comment: Wrong way to use `fscanf()`. For multiple reasons.

Comment: @iharob Could you please explain?

Comment: 1. You didn't check it's return value, which is a very common source of *undefined behavior*. 2. You didn't have the `&` address of operator in front of the `"%d"` matching parameters before (*when I commented*). 3. You don't limit the length of the `"%s"` specifiers even though you can, doing so prevents buffer overflowing.

Comment: @iharob I agree. But given that the question and the cases seemed simple enough, I thought of just giving a simple solution. It would still work most of the times. Your [down-voting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) is pretty harsh.

Comment: It wasn't when you didn't have the `&` but now it is, I agree. But now I don't like *It would still work most of the times*, it would not all of the time.

Comment: @iharob There. Thanks though!

Comment: Please take a look at the other answer. Wow!

Comment: I put the for loop after the    fscanf that gets in the total number of shifts and it didn't work. My program crashes.

Comment: Do I return anything from the read_data function back to the main function?

Comment: @A.Harm What error are you getting? Could you show your updated code?

Comment: In my new updated code I keep getting this error with my temp variable, any ideas why?  @alasin

Comment: Or if you have any ideas why?  @iharob

Comment: @A.Harm Please format your code correctly if you want help. And don't make this a new question, instead ask a new one.

Comment: @A.Harm really? that's so sad.